# jQuery POST to Sinatra API Same Origin Policy?

Tags: jquery, ruby, json, sinatra

I have developed an application using Sinatra for the API and jQuery/HTML5/Phonegap for the client side.

I have problems testing my application from a simple HTML5 that basically POSTs a request to my Sinatra API using JSON data.

I heard about JSONP but don't think is going to solve my problem since I use POST and not GET.

Are there any other solutions that I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [cross-domain XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests). To use it you need to send response header, which will allow interaction. In simplest case it's:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

With Sinatra you should write something like:

```
headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
```

One downside of such approach - not all browsers support cross-domain XHR by now, for example Opera doesn't.

Comment: I tried that with Sinatra but it seems to work with Safari but not with Firefox or Chrome. Since this is going to be compiled in PhoneGap then "Should I care about this?".